# Why the .mods files cannot be loaded when updating to Apache IoTDB Version 1.0?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Having problem synchronizing some ".mods" files.

I have updated to Apache IoTDB Version 1.0, and other files in previous IoTDB version can be loaded into Version 1.0, but the three ".mods" files cannot be synchronized. However, some other ".mods" files can be successfully loaded, but these three files cannot. What may be the reason for this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.mods` is a tombstone file, which records which data in the named tsfile has been deleted in Apache IoTDB. You can check whether these data has already been deleted in Version 1.0, causing the `.mods` files cannot be synchronized.
If these data are not deleted, and only these ".mods" files reported error when synchronizing, you can check whether the name of time series has anything wrong, and adjust it compared with the rules for using backticks in Version 1.0. Error may also be caused by the naming that did not suit backticks rules.